# How to define global constant (Q)Strings?

Tags: c++, qt, initialization, global-variables

Sometimes there is a need for magic strings, e.g. when accessing INI files, registry, REST APIs, ...

Let's assume a JSON key 'username':

There are different options on how to define this...

1. `#define JSON_USERNAME "username"`
2. `#define JSON_USERNAME (QString("username"))`
3. `#define JSON_USERNAME (QStringLiteral("username"))`
4. `QString const JSON_USERNAME("username")`
5. `QStringLiteral const JSON_USERNAME("username")`
6. `QLatin1String const JSON_USERNAME("username")`

or 7.:

```
QString JSON_USERNAME() {
    static QString const str("username");
    return str;
}
```

which needs to be used with parentheses: `JSON_USERNAME()`

... to only name a few.

Let's assume this simple use case:

```
// (cpp-file-)global definition of JSON_USERNAME = ("username")

bool hasUsername(QJsonObject &jo) {
    return jo.contains(JSON_USERNAME);
}
QString getUsername(QJsonObject &jo) {
    return jo.value(JSON_USERNAME).toString();
}
void setUsername(QJsonObject &jo, QString const &name) {
    jo.insert(JSON_USERNAME, name);
}
```

So there are:

- multiple occurences: one in each function
- called frequently: when parsing to / from JSON
- many different strings: one for each key

Each of the above methods has its drawbacks considering `QString("...")` performs a from-UTF-8-conversion and `QString` is implicitly shared:

1. UTF-8 conversion on every call (overhead)
2. same as 1
3. compile-time initialization, but at each place it is used (larger binary)

4.-6. global variable with unspecified instantiation

7. pro: lazy initialization, single shared instance, contra: need parentheses (unintuitive)

Is there a (Qt-specific) method that

- is token-like (can be used like a variable),
- is lazy-initialized,
- has little to no binary overhead (like a const char*) and
- has little to no run-time overhead (like a const QString)?

Comment: So you're basically looking for someone/some standard to approve of what you're doing instead of seeking the best solution for your own use-case?

Comment: Nope. I'm unhappy with what I'm currently using and have a feeling that it might be because I'm overlooking some best practices.

Comment: Usage should be at file scope (and you should not have dependencies and then avoid order initialization fiasco), so #5 or `static constexpr const char* JSON_USERNAME("username")` depending of type needed.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist: I tried to minimize the subjectiveness of my question. Asking to reopen

Comment: @mkaes Asking to reopen

Comment: @P.W Asking to reopen - there must be a more efficient way to reopen a question. Is there?

Comment: I'm an expert (see the close reason) on QString (see the commit log) and I don't see the point in even asking this. So why reopen. Make the strings you need. If there's a problem, the profiler will tell you and then you can solve whatever the *profiler* says is a problem. I bet the profiler won't ask *this* question.

Comment: @arnt So as a QString expert would you say there is no ideal method which satisifes all criteria, but instead I should choose for each case the best compromise between binary size and performance? That would seem like a perfectly viable answer to my question.

Comment: @arnt Also since my last edit this is basically a yes/no question and as such not opinion-based at all.

Comment: People can and do have opinions about yes/no questions. Particularly procrastination magnets like this one.

Answer (score 0):

I cant refer to global guidelines, but would vote for opt. 1.

Reason: config should remain config. 
Any kind of mixing configuration with executable code should be avoided for such reasons:

- You would probably want to move all your config to some kind of yaml/json tomorrow
- Sometime configuration moves to cmake or other toolkit. Imagine you force your future contributors fill CMAKE variables with values like 'QString("aa")'
- Config should be independent of implementation - your username doesn't depend on QString/QLatin1String or whatever you would like to use
- Config can be shared between different modules of your application and these modules can make different use of it.
- Executable global code... It gives you so little boost in performance, if we speak about converting utf-8, but you will fall into additional problems, connected with instance lifetime.